# why are child elements not moving to the next line when parent element has display property set to flex?

Tags: html, css

```
i mean div that has 's' class must go to the next line.
```

[link on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/054a2tug/)

```
<body>
            <div class="header">
            <div class="header-first">
            <div>FLYWHEEL <span>▼</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="header-second">
                <div class="one">PRODUCT <span>▼</span></div>
                <div class="s">S</div>
            
            </div>
            </div>
            </body>
            
             body{
                    background:linear-gradient(to bottom right,#3f557c,#8af3c7be,#e7800abe);
                    height:100vh;
                    padding:0px;
                    
                    
                    }
                .header{
                position: relative;
                height:20%;
                width:100%;
                margin:0px;
                
                
                }
                .header-first,.header-second{
                    position:relative;
                    float:left;
                    display:flex;
                    padding:0;
                    margin:0;
                    align-items: center;
                   justify-content: center;
                    background-color:rgb(129, 137, 173);
                    border-radius:30px;
                    box-sizing:border-box;
                    height:100%;
                    width:11.11%;
                    font-family: Comic Sans MS, Comic Sans;
                    color:rgba(255, 166, 0, 0.904);
                    font-size:16px;
                    
                   }
                   .s{
                   
                     border:3px solid red;
                   }
```

Why that div element doesnt go to the next line as it is supposed to be?
When parent element is displaying as  block element that div element with  's' class is moving to the next line
Does it have something to do with display:flex Or float:left?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the display property to flex, the default flex-direction is row. You can set `flex-direction: column` and the child elements will show up one below the other.

Read more about flex-direction at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction